# How to Add indicators in Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I am trying to add an indicator in Report Builder to show on my report using 2 fixed conditions. the first condition is if the description of a field  = "Compensation", the second being if a field date is >= Now(). It should then go red after 5 days.
I have added the indicator and in the Value and States tab, for Value I have added =(Fields!Description.Value ="Compensation")

For the indicator: Color Expression is "Yellow"
Start expression is =(fields!StartDate.value >=Now())
End expression is =(fields!StartDate.Value =Now()+5)

when I run the report, where the indicatr should be, I get text that reads "An error has occurred during data evaluation of the GaugePanel'GaugePanel5'.

Hope I've explained in enough detail.
Is anyone able to offer any advice on indicators please?
Thanks

Comment: I am not sure if this is causing your error but your end expression should be `Fields!StartDate.Value = Now.AddDays(5)`. Add more details and your expected results for further help.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I changed the expression and I'm not getting any errors, however I'm not getting the indicator to show either. I have a table that shows different types of complaints, Compensation being one type. Where it goes over a certain number of days, I am trying to get an indicator to show based on its age.

Comment: What type of gauge are you using? Also sample data could help.

Comment: I'm using an indicator which I have added to a new column within the table. I cant seem to add a screen shot.  the data in the table includes, Complaint Description and reported date. The complaint description could return 4 different complaint types. Compensation, Complaint Stage 1, Complaint Stage 2 and Board Review. For each of these complaint types, an indicator would show, yellow, green or red depending on how long it has been opened for e.g ReportedDate.

Comment: Edit your question to include sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using an expression under fill in Textbox Properties instead of adding an indicator which is giving me the required results. Example =IIF(Fields!ComplaintStageDescription.Value = "Stage0", "yellow", IIF(Fields!ComplaintStageDescription.Value = "Stage3", "white", IIF(Sum(Fields!DaysOpen.Value) < 5 ,"lime", IIF(Sum(Fields!DaysOpen.Value) < 10, "yellow" ,"red"))))